# returning instances in python

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

```
class classname():
     def func(self,a,b):
         self.c = a+b
         self.d = a-b
         self.e = a*b
     return self
cn = classname()
```

This way i can access cn.c, cn.d and cn.e can i use something else other then self to return it and it will be a structure. I know its possible in matlab where you can define structure in a function. Something what i expect should look like this:

```
class classname():
     def func(self,newself,a,b):
         self.c = a+b
         self.d = a-b
         newself.e = a*b
     return self, newself
cn = classname()
```

I know this is not a valid code but just an idea what i want from code.

Comment: You should read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial) to familiarize yourself with how classes work in Python.

Comment: What do you mean by newself and why do you want to use that?

Comment: newself is just a structure which contains value of e

Comment: First: your indentation isn't correct; second: there is the method `__init__` to use like a constructor; third: the constructor-like `__init__` don't return values; fourth: a function (or method) can return only one single value. The statement `return self, newself` still returns one single value - tupple with two members: `(self, newself)`. OOP is a little bit trick in the beginning, but don't give up. Read and learn.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this:

```
class classname:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.c = a+b
        self.d = a-b
        self.e = a*b
cn = classname(12, 34)  # Just random values for 'a' and 'b'. Use whatever you like!
print(cn.c)
>>> 46
print(cn.d)
>>> -22
print(cn.e)
>>> 408
```

The `__init__` function is automatically called when the object is created. Self will always refer to the object, so adding attributes to it will add it to the object, so you don't need to return anything.